# Telerik ComboBox Not Dropping Down List of Items

Tags: c#, jquery, combobox, telerik

I am using a Telerik ComboBox in my project and defined the markup of the control as follows:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(model => model.ReportType)                                                                
  .BindTo(ViewBag.lstFileType as SelectList)
  .AutoFill(true)
  .Placeholder(ReportsResources.ReportsResources.OptionLabelReportType)
  .SelectedIndex(0)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 298px;" }))
```

There are items in the ComboBox but when click to expand the ComboBox, it throws an error.

JS error in the console is as follows,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined     jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
c.documentElement.contains.m.contains                                jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
(anonymous function)                                                 telerik.combobox.min.js:1
g                                                                    jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
f.event.dispatch                                                     jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
h.handle.i                                                           jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
```

ComboBox doesn't expand. I'm using JQuery 1.7.1.

Comment: Are you sure the `contains` property is something that can be implicitly converted to a string and is not null? Also, are you sure its a public property?

Comment: Actually, this ComboBox was working properly in MVC3. This problem occurred after I upgraded the project from MVC3 to MVC5.